# Getting SQL/Linq-query variable to display 3 decimals for multi-type-variable items in one ListBox

Tags: c#, sql, xaml, listbox, winrt-xaml

Good day

Wonder if anyone can help.
I intend to display the rows containing the items for the following

```
public class Product
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int ChemID { get; set; }
    public string ChemCat { get; set; }
    public string ChemName { get; set; }
    public double ChemWeight { get; set; }
}
```

in the form of Xaml ListBox

```
<ListBox Name="listChems" Height="200" Width="300" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,5,0,0" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="18" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
                         <TextBlock Text="{Binding ChemCat}" Margin="10,0,0,0" Width="90" FontSize="14"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ChemName}" Margin="10,0,0,0" Width="90" FontSize="14"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ChemWeight}" Margin="10,0,0,0" Width="60" FontSize="14"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

using the usual SQL/Linq query

```
private void btnDisplayAll_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var display = conn.Table<Product>()
        .Select(g => g);

        listChems.ItemsSource = display;
    }
```

ChemCat and ChemName are purely strings eg. Lanthanide and Neodymium respectively.

However, I need to have ChemWeight (type double) to be displayed in 3 decimals, even if the user provide a number that has 0 or 1 or 2 decimals, ie.

```
1 to be displayed as 1.000 
1.4 to be displayed as 1.400
1.42 to be displayed as 1.420
```

How do I get SQL/Linq-query variable 'display' to force {Binding ChemWeight} to display 3 decimals, considering that the other members ChemCat and ChemName are strings and they are all tied together in a one ListBox.

(Earlier post said ChemPrice, it was meant to be ChemWeight)
Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For WPF**
Use the `StringFormat` property in the binding.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ChemPrice, StringFormat={}{0:0.000}}" Margin="10,0,0,0" Width="60" FontSize="14"/>
```

**For WINRT**
Use a `IValueConverter`

```
public class StringFormatConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return string.Format((string)parameter, value);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Note that you need to specify your converter for your control or window.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <local:StringFormatConverter x:Key="Converter"></local:StringFormatConverter>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ChemPrice, Converter={StaticResource Converter}, ConverterParameter=\{0:0.00\}}" Margin="10,0,0,0" Width="60" FontSize="14"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks for early reply. I got squiggly line underneath the word 'Binding' and 'StringFormat' and the error message says 'The property 'StringFormat' was not found in type 'Binding'. Did I miss something?

Comment: Sorry left out the `{}` from the start of the `StringFormat` - Try again

Comment: I wish I could paste the snapshot image showing the same error message appearing with the same squiggly lines underneath Binding and StringFormat. I am using VS Express 2015 for Windows 10.

Comment: The member "StringFormat" is not recognized or is not accessible.

Unknown member 'StringFormat' on element 'Binding'

The property 'StringFormat' was not found in type 'Binding'

Comment: I am using wpf, are you by any chance using winrt ;P

Comment: Also this project has SQLite.Net-PCL in it.

Comment: Yes, I am using winRT. Does this mean it wouldn't work? Oh man. Lets see if your suggestion work.

Comment: It worked. Thank you very much. I'll buy you a drink anytime when you're here in Kuala Lumpur. Thanks again.